# Concatenating two similar dataframes row-wise

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data-frames with same column names and similar data. How do I append/concatenate (row-wise) the second data-frame with the first?

For Example:

```
df1=

X1    X2    X3
1     a     x
2     b     y
3     c     z
```

and

```
df2=

X1    X2    X3
3     c     z
4     d     w
```

The result should be:

```
df_result=

X1    X2    X3
1     a     x
2     b     y
3     c     z
3     c     z
4     d     w
```

Where, X1, X2 and X3 are the column names.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2])` ?

Comment: This one works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use append()

```
df_result = df1.append(df2)
```

or if you want a continuing index:

```
df_result = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The first one works.